# way to Thread give up waiting and throws exception

Tags: java, multithreading, wait

Situation is there are two threads which are waiting for each other for some event.
and it is deadlock. In this case i want one thread to give up waiting and throw exception so that other thread can continue its task.
logically i can do that but is there any other way achieve this task?
what i have done :

```
boolean flag=true;
run(){
    synchronized(this){
    if(flag){
        boolean flag=false;
        wait(1500);
    }else{
        throw new Exception();
    }


    }
}
```

more description:
e.g
One ThreadA wants to add new customer(customerA) in customer table but 
he found that ThreadB already started this process so ThreadA waiting for ThreadB to complete (as customers id required for foreign key in another table )

ThreadB although completed insert into customerA , but it needs to insert some new city details to insert in city table but it is waiting as this processes is already started by ThreadA

And Both are waiting for each other to complete

Comment: Yeah, good luck finding a solution to deadlock.

Comment: +1 It seems the JVM should have this option. You get a report about deadlocks after all when you make a thread dump, so there is already code to detect deadlocks. There could be some (optional) facility to periodically check and resolve deadlocks (just like RDBMS do).

Comment: @Thilo - I don't quite understand.. How can an event be considered as a resource?. And how will 2 threads end up in a a deadlock based on an event?. *waiting for each other for some event*. They are not holding anything. They are just waiting..

Comment: @TheLostMind added description about the sample scenario.

Comment: You don’t have a deadlock. You simply have a `wait` call but there’s no recognizable condition you are waiting for. Normally another thread would call `notify` to allow the `wait` to end but this has to be complemented with a checkable condition which the waiting thread has to check (and recheck after `wait`) and the notifying thread must change to fulfilled. The only thing that looks like a condition is your `boolean` flag but since your waiting thread modifies that flag by itself before waiting, it all makes no sense.

Comment: @Holger you are getting it wrong , the code that i added was for Nikhil Talreja, what i have tried. boolean flag was not a condition for waiting thread, there is condition for waiting thread, and other thread is notifying only after changing the condition( that code is not here as is not related to my question). I just wanted to know the built in mechanism in java which can use for throwing exception after waiting for sometime and not fulfilling condtion.

Comment: @user3608352: so you’re saying the code you have posted to show what you have tried is *not* what you actually have tried? Then, what is the purpose of that nonsense code you have posted?

Comment: @Holger the code is only relevant part of my question,If you dont understand code then you can ask me more rather than declaring it nonsense.

Comment: @user3608352: I already explained what’s wrong with your code. If you refuse to deal with that, there’s no one who can help you.

Answer (score 0):

The way to *avoid* all strict deadlocks of his type is to always claim the same locks in the same order. In your example, both threads should update the City table first and the User table second, or they should both do it the other way around. Then deadlock cannot possibly arise.

Comment: thanks for you valuable input. But this is sample scenario, and in actual scenario issue is i cannot maintain ordering , for e.g Customer A may have other CustomerC (so recursively call the customer ), and Customer B dont have any other customer.

Comment: It doesn't matter. Detecting and recovering from deadlocks is extremely difficult. Avoiding them may require a little reorganisation of your application but it it is definitely the correct solution. Just treat it as a requirement, and code accordingly.